# Cell click event only happens once in kendo ui grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a click event being bound to a cell, but the click event only fires once from the very first row, when I step through the dataBound event it attaches itself, but only fires the one time

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
              read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
            },
            pageSize: 20
          },
          dataBound: function(e) {
            e.sender.tbody.find('td:eq(1)').on('click', function(e) {
              console.log("I was clicked");
            });
          },
          height: 550,
          groupable: true,
          sortable: true,
          pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
          },
          columns: [{
            template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
              "style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
              "<div class='customer-name'>#: ContactName #</div>",
            field: "ContactName",
            title: "Contact Name",
            width: 240
          }, {
            field: "ContactTitle",
            title: "Contact Title"
          }, {
            field: "CompanyName",
            title: "Company Name"
          }, {
            field: "Country",
            width: 150
          }]
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>

  <style type="text/css">
    .customer-photo {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-size: 32px 35px;
      background-position: center center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 32px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #999, inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .customer-name {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 32px;
      padding-left: 3px;
    }
  </style>


</body>
```

Comment: I'm not certain because while I have used other Telerik products I haven't used this one. But assuming their event naming is similar I think your problem might be that you are using the databound event of the whole grid that occurs only once. It doesn't occur for each row. Combine that with the fact that your selector limits to only the second td  as given here find('td:eq(1)') it only associates the click to that one td element. So only one td element in the whole grid is affected.

Comment: @J.Schmale, ah, you are right, once i put it into a loop to attach to every single row's cell then it worked. Thanks for the reminder on the dataBound event

Comment: @Chris are you saying that you want for the entire row to be clickable?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the dataBound event, add a class to the cell via column.attributes and then use event delegation to handle the click event on all cells with that class:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
          read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
        },
        pageSize: 20
      },
      height: 550,
      groupable: true,
      sortable: true,
      pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
      },
      columns: [{
        template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
          "style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
          "<div class='customer-name'>#: ContactName #</div>",
        field: "ContactName",
        title: "Contact Name",
        width: 240
      }, {
        field: "ContactTitle",
        title: "Contact Title",
                    attributes: {
                        "class": "CellClickHandler",
                    }
      }, {
        field: "CompanyName",
        title: "Company Name"
      }, {
        field: "Country",
        width: 150
      }]
    });
  });

$(document).on('click', '.CellClickHandler', function(e){
    console.log("I was clicked");
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    console.log("Contact Title: ",dataItem.ContactTitle);
});
```