# Add jQuery click event to button in KendoUI grid column template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

So, I have something working for this, but unfortunately it requires `onclick` in the column template to handle that specific row in my KendoUI grid. I'd like to replace this with a jQuery click event for maintainability purposes. One of the tricky thing is that this event requires the `Id` of the row where the button was clicked, but right now I'm more interested in getting to that event's code.

Here's a sample of what I have so far:

*Column Template*

```
// columns is a Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridColumnFactory of
// the type of the object I'm mapping to it

columns.Bound(p => p.SomeField).ClientTemplate(
    "<button type='button' class='btn btn-somefield'" + 
          "onclick='javascript:SomeAction(this, #=Id#);>" +
          "Some Button" +
    "</button>"
);
```

*JavaScript Function*

```
function SomeAction(el, id){
    var reqUrl = 'someUrl' + '?id=' + id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: reqUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (content) {
            console.log('request successful for id: ' + id);
        }
    });
}
```

What I have for the jQuery implementation:

*Column Template*

```
columns.Bound(p => p.SomeField).ClientTemplate(
    "<button type='button' class='btn btn-somefield'>" +
          "Some Button" +
    "</button>"
);
```

*jQuery Function*

```
$('.btn-somefield').on('click', function(){
    // Here I have some unfinished code to get the Id and everything.
    // I'm not too concerned about figuring this out in this question, 
    // but suggestions are welcome

    // Otherwise it's the same body as the plain JS function
});
```

To sum it up: right now that jQuery event just isn't getting hit when the button is clicked. I have tried numerous different iterations along the lines of things like this: `$(selector).on('click', function(){});` and `$(selector).click(function(){});` but with no success.

I am concerned about how to pull out that row's Id once I actually get to the event handler, but right now I just need to hit the event after clicking the button.

(Also, the overall project is an asp.net mvc application if that makes any difference to anybody.)

Comment: When is your jQuery function being called? If it is happening before your column contents are rendered then it won't find the buttons to attach to.

Comment: @J.Schmale It's defined inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ });` block. Otherwise it's just a regular click event.

Comment: Can you create a dojo of your implementation and share?

Comment: Maybe attach your onclick event in the databound event of the grid. This article shows an example of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881754/cell-click-event-only-happens-once-in-kendo-ui-grid

Comment: Add a data-id attribute to your template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [jQuery event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). This allows you to create the event handler before the grid buttons are generated. Then to get the ID, you can get the dataItem for the grid row using the [dataItem() method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/dataitem):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-somefield', function(e){
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
  var ID = dataItem.Id;
});
```